# Is there a tool for Visual Studio to track (or break on) variable value?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

Is there is a tool or a setting in the Visual Studio debugger to stop on breakpoints or when a variable is set to a particular value? I mean, if I know that value will be set to "HELLO," I want the debugger will stop the same way it would if it reached a breakpoint?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for a [Conditional Breakpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sye83ce.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

1. Set a breakpoint anywhere in code.

   - Enable the list of breakpoints window by going to Debug menu -> Windows -> Breakpoints.
   - In your breakpoints window, right click on a breakpoint
   - Select Condition...
   - Enter any expression involving your variable

The breakpoint will be hit when the condition is met.

Via the right click on breakpoints menu, you can also set breakpoints:

- Only from certain processes or threads
- Upon hit counts
- Only when a condition or variable is changed

Comment: Can you do string comparisons there?

Comment: You can try and if it doesn't work you can for example only set a value to true in code when it's equal, and then use that as your condition.

Answer (score 4):

there are watchpoints.

Answer (score 3):

Daves answer.

And I'll add that you can just add a if statement that contains a couple of dummy statements and you put a breakpoint inside it. It does the same thing.

Typical use :

```
if (i == 250) {
 int dummy = 2+2;  //breakpoint here
}
```

In your case, since you watch the value of a string (assuming C++ strings)

```
if (mystring == "hello")
{
  int dummy = 2+2; //breakpoint here
}
```

Comment: Or use DebugBreak() to break into the debugger and skip the dummy statement.

Answer (score 0):

try - `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(yourVariable <> "HELLO")` and then click on 'Cancel' button to start debugging. This works for ASP.net and Silverlight projects